# Jquery with call back functions

Tags: jquery, css, function, callback

i have one problem with the Jquery callback functions, here is the link:
http://saveenergy.metropolia.fi/views/pihkapuisto/
as you can see, the first page works fine. but all the others are not fine. they always right side and the size is too small. anyone knows how to change the position and size, make it looks like the first one? thanks

Answer (score 1):

you may need to use .live() as i believe you are loading elements from scratch,  .live() uses delegation thus looks for new objects that are added to the browser...